# How do I validate a number input within a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation

In my `return` statement, I try to check for a valid number or else assign the value 0. This doesn't seem to work, is there a different way of doing this?

```
return (
    <Input
      color="teal"
      size="regular"
      outline={true}
      type={question?.type}
      name={question?.name}
      value={value ?? ''}
      placeholder={question?.placeholder ?? ''}
      onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (question?.type === 'number' && Number(e.currentTarget.value) < 1) {
          e.currentTarget.value = 0;
        }
        dispatch(
          setResponseGeneric({
            property: question?.name,
            value: e.currentTarget.value,
          })
        );
      }}
    ></Input>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Number('bad input')` returns `NaN` (Not a Number). `NaN` is a value which is not smaller or greater than 1. You should change your condition so that it handles those scenarios.

```js
if (question?.type === 'number' && (isNaN(e.currentTarget.value) || Number(e.currentTarget.value) < 1)) {
```

Also something else, besides your question, changing the element value like you do in here `e.currentTarget.value = 0;` is bad practice since you're changing it imperatively. It's better to make sure you're changing the state so that the `value` variable becomes 0 (I'm not sure if that already happens in `setResponseGeneric`).

Comment: You are right actually, I'm not changing the state in ```setResponseGeneric``` not sure how to. Pretty new to react.